# EntityFramework Core InMemory database - Seed data from SQL tables or Script into memory repository

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, in-memory-database, seed

I am trying to run one application that is already in production with a EntityFramework core Database First.

I have my Context and Model as POCOs.

Now I am trying to run this in my laptop which can't have a full database running so I am trying to use **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory**, but I need to seed the data that I have in SQL Scripts.

I tried search this but I can't find it a way to do the following:

- I have a Sql script with all insert data into the database.
- Get each table and create C# seed data model to inject into modelBuilder.Entity().HasData(....

Since its a InMemory database, I think it's only possible to seed data through models and not SQL Scripts, so this is the problem I am facing ATM which I don't find a "ready to go solution" on this.

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

In-Memory has its own limitations and if its for pure testing purposes, you can try SqlLite, which has lesser limitations

Comment: This is not really the way I wanna go, because SQLIte has a different way of writing scripts, autoincrement and Integer types where we don't have in MSSQL database.
For this I need fix all my scripts which is big pain and error prone, where isn't the way I wanna go